# Requery Subform Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vba

I was just wondering if somebody could help with my subform not requering. My aim is that once a record is added in to my subform, I shouldn't have to push the 'Refresh All' button, I want it to refresh automatically. I have tried the following coding on After Insert of the Main Form, and on the Subform, but it hasn't worked. If anybody has any other ideas of how to do so apart from the way I tried, that would be great, thank you.

Creations is the name of the Form.

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
    Form![Creations].Requery
End Sub
```

and

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "Creations", acSaveNo
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Creations
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not me.requery? And why do you need to requery?

Comment: I need to requery because the records are being added in to the subform from  a command button, this needs to be refreshed automatically, which is not doing so at this moment in time. Me.Requery alone didnt work, also should it go on the After Update of the Form or of the Subform please?

Answer (score 3):

If you are adding records via code, the requery should go in the procedure that adds the records. Most events are not triggered by programmatic changes to data.

For code running in the subform:

```
Me.Requery
```

The main form:

```
Me.Subformcontrolname.Form.Requery
```

Elsewhere

```
Forms!Mainformname.Subformcontrolname.Form.Requery
```

Comment: Sorry I dont quite understand what you mean, do you have any other alternatives that I could try out.

Comment: I tried the top two but it still isnt working, do you have any idea why that could be?

Comment: You said "I need to requery because the records are being added in to the subform from a command button" how are the records being added? Post your code.

Comment: Events are not fired when changes are made programmatically. There is not much point trying everything, find out where you are running the code.

Comment: Through SQL in Visual Basic, when I add the records it is not automatically refreshing.
    
    Private Sub CocaCola_Click()
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    strSQL = "INSERT into tbl_order (Description, Price)"
    strSQL = strSQL & " VALUES('Coca Cola', '£1.90');"
    dbs.Execute (strSQL)
    End Sub

Comment: I know where it needs to go but because I have tried it so many times, I have tried it on the different functions because it didnt work on the original places I tried.

Comment: So did you put a requery in `Private Sub CocaCola_Click()`? Because that is where it needs to go. Events are not triggered by programmatic changes.

Comment: Ive tried that just now, before EndSub, but it didnt work, oh the joys of coding not working.

Comment: So the new coding is Private Sub CocaCola_Click() Dim dbs As DAO.Database Set dbs = CurrentDb strSQL = "INSERT into tbl_order (Description, Price)" strSQL = strSQL & " VALUES('Coca Cola', '£1.90');" dbs.Execute (strSQL) Me.Requery End Sub, its annoying me so much that this isnt working.

Comment: I have tried the coding just posted here and it didnt automatically refresh, to show the record in the subform I still had to manually refresh.

Comment: So the coding is adding to the coreesponding table but it only shows these results in the subform when i refresh it, i was just wondering whether I have made it clear enough, if you need further clarification please let me know.

Comment: I have been stuck on this for a few days now, does anybody have any ideas please?

Comment: It is best to answer the questions, Which module is CocaCola_Click() in?